# How to get the first 5 numbers from a number with google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

in one column in my spreadsheet are just numbers. something like this:

```
1212133
1343255
1234566
```

i want to itterate over this column and create an array which contains only the fisrt 5 numbers from each number: [12121, 13432, 12345] and than the max number (in this example: 13432). Can somebody help me? Any ideas?

```
function    maxFromFirstFiveNumbers(){      
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
 var firstColumn = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues;    
 for (var i = 0; i <= firstColumn.length; ++i) {        
 // from hier i need help!!     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFirst5IntoArray(){      
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var first5A=[];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    first5A.push(vA[i][0].toString().substr(0,5));//substr method of strings
  }
  return first5A;
}
```

> [substr method of strings reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: thank you, Cooper. It works. :D But how can i get the max from array?

Comment: Go to the reference I gave you and search for the sort method for arrays. You will have to add a comparison function to get it to sort numerically but it’s all explained there.